# Using python to parse twitter url

Tags: twitter, python-3.5, url-parsing

I am using the following code but I am not able to extract any information from the url.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    z = 5
    url = 'https://twitter.com/isro/status/1170331318132957184'
    df = urlparse(url)
    print(df)

ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='twitter.com', path='/isro/status/1170331318132957184', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

I was hoping to extract the tweet message, time of tweet and other information available from the link but the code above clearly doesn't achieve that. How do I go about it from here ?

```
print(df)
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='twitter.com', path='/isro/status/1170331318132957184', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Comment: what is `ParseResult`?

Comment: It is coming out of the print result. Why the downvote ?

Comment: I didn't downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the purpose of the urllib parseurl function. From the Python documentation:

> urllib.parse.urlparse(urlstring, scheme='', allow_fragments=True)
>
> Parse a URL into six components, returning a 6-item named tuple. This
> corresponds to the general structure of a URL:
> scheme://netloc/path;parameters?query#fragment

From the result you are seeing in ParseResult, your code is working perfectly - it is breaking your URL up into the component parts.

It sounds as though you actually want to *fetch* the web content at that URL. In that case, I might take a look at urllib.request.urlopen instead.